# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-image

> Code

```
PickedFile? _imageFile;
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    


    CircleAvatar(
       radius: 80.0,
       backgroundImage: _imageFile == null
       ? AssetImage('assets/person.png')
       : FileImage(File(_imageFile.path))
  ),
```

The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider?

Guys can anyone help me to solve this error
The Asset Image is working fine but in the FileImage it shows an error
I also tried with importing the dart:io pakage but this also does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way

```dart
backgroundImage: _imageFile == null
    ? AssetImage('assets/person.png')
    : FileImage(File(_imageFile!.path)) as ImageProvider,
```

Also try using

```dart
  XFile? _imageFile;
 ...
 final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: source,
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to clear this error

Comment: Glad to help, you can check more about [image-picker-plugin-for-flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#image-picker-plugin-for-flutter)

Comment: _imageFile = NetworkHandler().getImage(profileModel.username);

Comment: It depends on both side data types

Comment: `_imageFile = NetworkHandler().getImage(profileModel.username); `

**A value of type 'NetworkImage' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PickedFile?'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'PickedFile?**

Comment: `NetworkHandler().getImage(profileModel.username)` returns a Image object, you cant assign it to 'PickedFile?'. you can create another variable (Image) and use it